# Plotly - How do I plot a line on a map from a json file?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot a line on a map in plotly from a json file and keep receiving the following error. All the examples on the plotly website use a .csv file. However, I'd like to use a json file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Error: No valid mapbox style found, please set `mapbox.style` to one of:
>   open-street-map, white-bg, carto-positron, carto-darkmatter, stamen-terrain, stamen-toner, stamen-watercolor
>   or register a Mapbox access token to use a Mapbox-served style.

**Python:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('fcRailroad.geojson') as json_file:
    fcRailroad = json.load(json_file)

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox())

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="stamen-terrain", 
                mapbox_zoom=10, 
                mapbox_center_lat = 40.58,
                mapbox_center_lon = -105.08,
                margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0},
                mapbox=go.layout.Mapbox(
                    layers=[{
                        'sourcetype': 'geojson',
                        'source': fcRailroad,
                        'type': 'line',
                    }]
                ))

fig.show()
```

**Json:**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -825.0913953781128,
                        40.49348616373978
                    ],
                    [
                        -825.0906443595885,
                        40.49508532104079
                    ],
                    [
                        -825.0863313674927,
                        40.502411585011934
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading the json file correctly. You're trying to read the "fcRailroad.json" as json. And it is obviously not valid json. This is how you load the content from the file:

```
with open('fcRailroad.json') as json_file:
    fcRailroad = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I be reading it as geojson? The file is the correct type because I can plot the line in leaflet but am having a hard time with plotly.

Comment: As far as I can tell your data is poorly formatted. And I have no idea what you're trying to plot. But you shouldn't you only use the coordinates. There is no [geojson](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.line_mapbox.html) in line_mapbox()

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. After going through several pages of plotly docs I went with plotly.graph_objects and have updated the code. Crazy how there is no geojson attribute for plotting maps in plotly, makes no sense. I don't see anything wrong with my geojson file but the new error received happens after I added the mapbox attribute. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help. Also Im trying to plot a line on the map. It follows railroad tracks.